# IntegrityError:NOT NULL constraint failed: chatapp_chat.message

Tags: python, django

I'm writing chat application in Django and after subbing my message I get error:

```
IntegrityError at /chatapp/post/ NOT NULL constraint failed: chatapp_chat.message
```

This is my models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Chat(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null=True)
    message = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.message
```

This is my view.py

```
def home(request):
    c = Chat.objects.all()
    return render(request, "chatapp/home.html", {'home': 'active', 'chat': c})

def post(request):
    if request.method == "POST":

        msg = request.POST.get('msgbox', None)

        c = Chat(user=request.user, message=msg)
        if msg != '':
            c.save()
        return JsonResponse({ 'msg': msg, 'user': c.user.username })
    else:
        return HttpResponse('Request must be POST.')

def messages(request):
    c = Chat.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'chatapp/messages.html', {'chat': c})
```

And .html

```
<body>

        <div class="panel-heading">Chat Box</div>
        <div id="msg-list-div" class="panel-body">
            <ul id="msg-list" class="list-group">
                {% for obj in chat %}
                    {% if obj.user == request.user %}
                        <li class="text-right list-group-item">{{ obj.message }}</li>
                    {% else %}
                        <li class="text-left list-group-item">{{ obj.message }}</li>
                    {% endif %}
                {% empty %}
                    <li class="text-right list-group-item">No messages yet!</li>
                {% endfor %}
                <script>
                    var chatlist = document.getElementById('msg-list-div');
                    chatlist.scrollTop = chatlist.scrollHeight;
                </script>
            </ul>
        </div>


    <form id="chat-form" method="post" action="/chatapp/post/">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div id="chat-bottom" class="input-group">
            <input type="text" id="chat-msg" name="chat-msg" class="form-control"/>
            <span class="input-group-btn">
                <input class="btn btn-default" id="send" type="submit" value="Send"/>
            </span>
```

I've searched through lot of answers but couldn't find the right solution for my problem.

Comment: Your chat message field name is `chat-msg` but you are accessing it by using the name `msgbox`. That is why `msg = request.POST.get('msgbox', None)` this line always returns `None`. And your if condition is not checking for `None`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Erorr occurs when you post empty message (or even 'msgbox' var is absent in post vars) that converts to `None` in this line: `msg = request.POST.get('msgbox', None)`. I would change this block with empty string check:

```
    msg = request.POST.get('msgbox', None)
    c = Chat(user=request.user, message=msg)
    if msg != '':
        c.save()
```

to:

```
    msg = request.POST.get('msgbox', '').strip()
    if msg:
        c = Chat.objects.create(user=request.user, message=msg)
        return JsonResponse({ 'msg': msg, 'user': c.user.username })
    else:
        return JsonResponse({'some status': 'indicating that empty/no msg posted'})
        # or no return anything
```

**update:** and change var name `'msgbox'` to `'chat-msg'` according to your form input name.

Comment: I tried and now I get this error message: local variable 'c' referenced before assignment. And if I assign it before like msg = request.POST.get('msgbox', None)
    c = Chat(user=request.user, message=msg)
    if msg != '':
        c.save()

Comment: Yes, I tried and got error mess: local variable 'c' referenced before assignment

Comment: @user3599620 that because you try to always use `c` in JsonResponse but there is no `c` var in case if no msg received... check update

Comment: Now it gives me mess {"some status": "indicating that empty/no msg posted"} which means message that I wrote didn't get in at all.

Comment: @user3599620 your form variable name is "chat-msg"? if so, change 'msgbox' to 'chat-msg'

Answer (score 0):

Your `message` field does not accept empty values. Change it to

```
message = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, default='')
```

In other case, if you message must be provided and cannot be empty, make no changes to the model, but handle this validation in forms, so that you are sure that your view gets fully validated data.